# How to delete gitlab job logs automatically after certain time?

Tags: logging, automation, gitlab, pipeline

In my git repo Jobs logs are consuming a lot of space and I have to delete it jobs manually every week using the curl in order to delete associated logs.

I have gone through couple of articles, and concluded that:

1. We can't delete Gitlab Jobs or Piplines automatically after some time, this is manual process only either from UI or using Curl.
2. We can delete artifacts using `expire_in`.

But is there any way to delete or expire Pipeline and Jobs logs also in Gitlab in some automated way as we do for artifacts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible on GitLab.com, as [stated in the documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/job_logs.html#how-to-remove-job-logs):

> There isn’t a way to automatically expire old job logs

Self-hosted GitLab administrators, however, do have an option to simply delete the log files from the filesystem (or remote storage, if configured). This could be setup in a cronjob, for example:

```sh
find /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts -name "job.log" -mtime +60 -delete
```

An alternative (that would work on gitlab.com or self-hosted) would be to setup some automation scripts (maybe as a scheduled GitLab pipeline?) that uses the GitLab API to locate old pipelines and delete them.

Pseudo code:

```py
def get_all_projects() -> List[Project]:
    # https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#list-all-projects
    ...

def get_project_pipelines(project: Project) -> List[Pipeline]:
    # https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html#list-project-pipelines
    # https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html#get-a-single-pipeline
    ...

today = datetime.today()
threshold = today - timedelta(days=60)
for project in get_all_projects():
    for pipeline in get_project_pipelines(project):
        if pipeline.finished_at < threshold:
            print('deleting', pipeline.id, 'from project', project.id)
            pipeline.delete()
```

You could run such a script on a schedule (say, in a scheduled pipeline itself?) to regularly remove your old pipelines.

Comment: Thanks, I have made it work with Scheduled Python Script

Comment: When I call these Gitlab APIs, it needs my AccessTokens, else it's giving error. Is there any way to run it without Tokens or anyway where I can store my AccessTokens in some encrypted way, so that no one else can see it?